# Spring boot , Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org/SpringFramework/boot/SpringApplication

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring-boot maven application that runs fine in eclipse but when i try to do java -jar "jarname".jar it throws an exception

Because of this i am not able to start the application on one of my local servers which run ubuntu

```
         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
                at com.rzt.apps.shredsk.springmvc.Application.main(Application.java:15)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
                ... 1 more
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.shredsk</groupId>
 <artifactId>ShredsK</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
 <properties>
    <start-class>com.rzt.apps.shredsk.springmvc.Application</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- jsr303 validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--apache commons utils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>ShredsK</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>analyze</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze-dep-mgt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <failBuild>true</failBuild>
                            <ignoreDirect>false</ignoreDirect>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How are you creating the jar? Also I strongly suggest using the `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies instead of defining everything yourself.

Comment: I figured out the cause , the dependencies were  not added in the jar that was created !! @Deinum . i was running maven goal : mvn clean install

Thanks for your response and feedback on using spring-boot-starter !

Comment: Did you try to following things?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52738836/9243717

Answer (score 6):

You need to set build attribute.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you create your jar using *mvn clean package* ?

Comment: Yes i did , but then too i was facing that issue , its now its fixed ! Thank You

Comment: What was the fix ?

Comment: @ShreeshaN What was the fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) document carefully  , you should be able to build the jar file and run the app , I was running into the same issue searched various options nothing worked, finally , I rewrote the pom file and ran the below command 
mvn package && java -jar target/jarname.jar

It worked !

Answer (score -2):

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This will take care of the packaging. Believe me